# Docker Swarm Mode W/Terraform Digital Ocean Load Balancing. How to Auto Scale?

Tags: docker, digital-ocean, devops, docker-swarm, terraform

So I've been able to answer most of my questions through this article here

https://knpw.rs/blog/docker-swarm-terraform/

My question is from the point where this article ends, how do I do automatic scaling based on metrics like **CPU usage** and **Network usage?**

For example create a new instance if my CPU usage is above 70% on all the nodes, and destroy an instance if the CPU usages falls below 30%.  **These would have to be sustained usages of course, like all nodes running at more than 70% CPU Usage for more than 5 minutes.**

I did some research into this but its not very clear.  For example **Digital Ocean has a monitoring service which can send you an email if the CPU Usage is abnormally high** (or Networking Load) based on a threshold you set.  **The problem is** **they don't have WebHook support** yet so I can't send these signals to my application.

One idea I had was to **set a special email for these notifications** and check the email.  **Based on the email response I then create a modified terraform file and `'terraform apply'` it to modify the infrastructure?**

I'm not sure if this is good form either **since the point of terraform is code as infrastructure, but if the infrastructure is designed to create new instances and destroy instances all the time based on CPU Usage or Network Usage I'm not sure how you convey that concept correctly in terraform?**

Any pointers in the right direction is appreciated, I'm pretty stuck on where to turn at this point.  Maybe terraform is not good for this type of setup?

Comment: I'm not sure what you would do with DO but in AWS you'd simply use autoscaling groups that respond to alarms on your chosen metrics to scale in and out. If DO doesn't support that kind of thing then you'll need to jerry rig something that when an email alert is sent out that email is automatically read and then a system interprets that to fire Terraform with vars specified on the command line or something. It sounds pretty awful though.

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-automate-the-scaling-of-your-web-application-on-digitalocean

Comment: Maybe AWS is only solution for this?

Comment: Are there any other auto scaling cloud providers?

Comment: Have a look at Kubernetes, maybe this solution is good for you. Looks like it does not depend on cloud provider. Here's some links:  
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/

Comment: Kubernetes supports cluster autoscaling for GCE out of the box https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/cluster-management/#resizing-a-cluster. Also it has good REST API so you can integrate it with your cloud provider.

Comment: Can the kubernetes setup on GCE be described in a terraform file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this question is not related to Digital Ocean. The solution you could build for Digital Ocean could work for all other Cloud providers as long as they provide an API for creating/destroying nodes.

So either you switch to AWS which has a built-in auto-scaling, either you build your own solution. It's a lot of work but it's not hard to set up. You need to have a full visibility on your cluster like a monitoring system that track all your cluster nodes from a node registry/discovery and then collect metrics and trigger alerts.

You may configure you alert system to run your Terraform job, ansible playbooks, trigger a Jenkins Job via HTTP api,... that will scale in/out your infrastructure based on the metrics.

Comment: Is there a solution for auto scaling with digital oceans service already that I could easily adapt to terraform? I saw some consul solutions possibly but I think that is a replacement for docker swarm

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, I don't think there is. As I said you should build your own auto-scaling solution.

Comment: I saw an auto scaling option with google container service and kubernetes but not sure if this can be setup with terraform? curious your thoughts on that.

Comment: Yeah I think GCE, like AWS, has a built-in nodes autoscaler (https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/autoscaler/). Regarding kuburnetes, it supports auto-scaling pods (not nodes), which means that it can auto scale your running services across your existing nodes.

Comment: Do you know if the GCE node autoscaler can be described via terraform, I looked on terraforms provider info but coudn't see anything for that yet.  Maybe its because its in beta

Comment: I think it can be managed via Terraform (https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/compute_autoscaler.html)

Comment: I saw it could do CPU as one of the metrics

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154595/discussion-between-hamou92-and-joseph-astrahan).